# Rails ActiveAdmin, two columns (not sidebar) on form page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activeadmin

In a form in active admin, the fields expand horizontally across the page according to the size of the window. If it's a big monitor, there is a lot of "unused" space to the right.

How can I add a "column" (NOT a side bar) to the right of the page so that I will end up with a 50% width section of the form on the left and a 50% width section of the form on the right?

I need this because I have lots of fields.

This is what my form partially looks like right now...

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Shipment Details" do
    f.input :file_number
    f.input :customer, :label_method => :company_name
    f.input :shipper, :label_method => :company_name
    f.input :broker, :label_method => :company_name
  end
    f.inputs "Places" do
    f.input :place_of_origin, :as => :select, :collection => Place.find(:all, :order => "city", :select => "city").map(&:city)
    f.input :place_of_loading, :as => :select, :collection => Place.find(:all, :order => "city", :select => "city").map(&:city)
    f.input :place_of_delivery, :as => :select, :collection => Place.find(:all, :order => "city", :select => "city").map(&:city)
    f.input :via, :as => :select, :collection => Place.find(:all, :order => "city", :select => "city").map(&:city)
  end
  f.inputs "Carrier" do
    f.input :carrier, :label_method => :company_name
    f.input :mode, :as => :select,
    :collection => ["Air", "Air Collect", "Air Prepaid", "FCL", "FTL", "LCL", "LTL", "TBA"]
    f.input :mbl, :label => "MBL"
    f.input :hbl, :label => "HQL"
    f.input :vessel
    f.input :container
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

Answer (score 7):

It's pretty simple, you can give each section of your inputs a CSS class, then you would modify active_admin.css.scss (or just .css) so it would float your forms to the correct place, as well as give them a correct width, etc.

Comment: Correct, if you are looking to simply style the content differently, you would use CSS to do this.

Comment: Cool, I was trying to see if there is a way to do it by using the existing activeadmin CSS, but if there isn't, then I'll follow your suggestion. Will try it in a bit.

Comment: Keep in mind that you should scope all activeadmin CSS inside "body.active_admin" (or "body.active_admin.my_namespace" if you're using several activeadmin namespaces and you only want this CSS to affect the "my" namespace)